# Svelte - import const from component does not work

Tags: javascript, svelte, rollup

I try to import a const value from a Svelte component, but rollup says, the component does not export this value.
What do I wrong, or is it a rollup problem ?

[related REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f62136ad37d242c2a6ab16ae22b0dc3a?version=3)

Component.svelte:

```js
<script>
export const answer = 42;
</script>
```

App.svelte:

```js
<script>
import { answer } from './Component.svelte';
</script>

<h1>{answer}</h1>
```

The same problem appears when importing an enum definition.

Comment: try replacing <script> with <script context="module"> in Component.svelte. I have added this as a answer below.

Comment: more about it in here: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/module-exports

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Svelte use the `export` syntax to define a component props. So if you want to use this `export` like you do in modern javascript modules you have to indicate it to the Svelte compiler using `context="module"` like:

```html
<script context="module">
    export const answer = 42;
</script>
```

Checkout the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e8ad7d24b87c41abbf54352a0cc716d0?version=3.31.0) and the [doc](https://svelte.dev/docs#script_context_module) to learn a little more about it.

Comment: Note that this code and the REPL linked work correctly, but if you're using the Svelte IntelliJ plugin v0.20.0 - it will incorrectly complain about the import as per this issue: https://github.com/tomblachut/svelte-intellij/issues/241

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing  with  in Component.svelte. But please note it’ll be read-only no matter how you define it (const or let), so if you want to change the value you may want to create setter or getter function to do that and then access the variable using that.

```
 <script context="module">
    export const answer = 42;
 </script>
```